# Images don't show up in GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a website on GitHub pages. When I tried to incorporate an image in a `post.md` file, the image works in the GitHub, but not in the website.

I wrote `![](images/em.png)` in the Markdown file and it looked good when I saw the preview of changes. However, when I look at the website I've created, it doesn't work and shows a question mark like this:

[image: image of question mark]

Comment: Are you checking the image in to source control along with the markdown file? Are you uploading the image to wherever you're hosting your site?

Comment: Your browser's debugging tool is your friend here. `Inspect` your webpage to get more insight into the error.

Comment: You're going to need to open up your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) to the networking tab to see where your site is trying to load the image from.

Comment: In addition to the comments above about inspecting the page, you may need a `/` in front of `images/em.png`.